# Generating a soft circluar mask using numpy (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, geometry, area

I need to generate circular masks that represent receptive fields in the human eye. The main problem is that I'm not sure how to calculate the percentage of area covered by pixels that are partially outside the circle. For example, consider this simple code for generating a circular mask:

```
def circle(size=19, r=7, x_offset=0, y_offset=0):
    x0 = y0 = size // 2
    x0 += x_offset
    y0 += y_offset
    y, x = np.ogrid[:size, :size]
    y = y[::-1]

    return ((x - x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2)<= r**2
```

which generates this circle:

[image]

As you can see the output is binary and if the circle covers at least 50% of the area, its weight is set to 1 and if it's less than 50% coverage, it's set to 0. Here is an overlay, showing it more clearly:

[image]

Another common method of generating circles that appear more smooth is to use a 2D gaussian:

```
def gaussian2d(size=19, sigma = 3, amplitude=1, x_offset=0, y_offset=0):
    x = np.arange(0, size, 1, float)
    y = x[:,np.newaxis][::-1]
    x0 = y0 = size // 2
    x0 += x_offset
    y0 += y_offset

    return amplitude*np.exp(-(((x-x0)**2 /(2*sigma**2)) + ((y-y0)**2 /(2*sigma**2))))
```

resulting in an output that looks like this:

[image]

This solves the problem with the binary output (weights set to 1 or 0), but the problem is that the weights start decreasing even for pixels that are 100% covered by the circle, which is not correct.

ideally, the mask should look something like this (this is hand-drawn):

[image]

The pixels that are 100% covered by the circle are set to 1 and the ones that are partially covered, are set to the percentage area covered by the circle, for example:

[image]

The efficiency (both in terms of runtime and memory usage) isn't all that important, I just need a way to calculate the percentage of the area of the pixel, that is covered by the circle. Accuracy isn't super important either and a 1% error should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A box and a circle may overlap or not. If the four corners are inside the circle, then that's 100% of your "percentage of the area" target.

So the first step is calculate the four distances from the corners to the center of the circle.

```
di = sqrt((xi-xc)^2 + (yi-yc)^2)
```

If all `di` are greater or equal to the radius `R` of the circle then box is outside the circle. Similary, if all corners verify `di <= R` then the cell is totally inside the circle.

The rest of cases have one to three corners inside the circle.

Let's see this "one corner outside" case:

[image]

The point is calculate the coordinates of points `P,Q`.

Because you know A-B is horizontal you can get the `xQ` coordinate by using the `y` coordinate (same for A and B)

```
xQ= xc + sqrt(R^2-(yA-yc)^2)
```

where `xc,yc` are the coordinates of the center of the circle. Notice that `yQ = yA = yB`

Be aware you can get two values, depending on the sign of the sqrt you use. Take the one that is `xA <= xQ <= xB`.

Similary, using `xA` you can find `xP`.

In this moment you know all coordinates.

 Pay attention to straight `P,Q`. The area below it is easy, just some triangles. Or the total area of the cell deducing the triangle `P,A,Q`.

The area between the straight and the circumference is the area of a circular sector (which you can browse the Internet to find it) minus a triangle.

You'll need to find the angle of this sector. For that, I advise to use `atan2` instead of `atan`, because the former gives an angle in (0, 2pi) range. And you must work with the substraction `atan2(f1)-atan2(f2)` normalized into (0,pi) range.

You can draw other cases (e.g. three corners out) and using those methods above find the area you need.

For example you have a box with two corners out, but don't know which sides the circle cross. You can test a side by this:

- Get a side (let's call it AB). If it's horizontal you know its `y= yA=yB` coordinate.
- Find the `x`  coord in circle for this `y` (two solutions, +x,-x)
- Test `xA < x xB`. If both solutions fail then the circle doesn't cross this side.

If the side is vertical then use its `y` coord to find the `x` one.

If a side has both corners out, then you can avoid testing it.

### An easy approximation

Very similar to [Montecarlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)

For those cells that are crossing the circuference (some but not all corners are outside) you can sub-divide each one into a `n x n` grid, and test every sub-cell.

The test can be the distance from the center of the subcell (e.g. average point of its diagonal) to the center of the circle.

You assign area=0 if `dist > R` and area=1 otherwise.

Then the "assigned" area of the cell is the mean; this is, the summatory of all assigned areas of the n^2 subcells, divided by the area of the cell (which is nxn).

In the worst case there are about `n` subcells with wrong assigned area. This is `n/n^2 = 1/n` error. So if you want to calculate with an error less than 1% you need a 100x100 grid for the grid in a cell.

Comment: I will have a go at implementing it today. Thanks.

Comment: This actually gets too messy quickly. Have a look at this: [image](https://i.imgur.com/1EKzgGZ.jpg)
How do we know which of the cases is true? Y coordinate of Q and X coordinate of P will be different in each case. Other than hand-coding every possibility, is there another way to know? Edit: it's even worse if the center is not perfectly aligned with the grid, because the cases won't be symmetric either.

Comment: @OM222O Yes, I've edited the answer to explain it a bit more. Anyhow, you can't avoid testing cell by cell. And yes, there are many a bunch of cases (not that many) you must test one by one.

Comment: I don't think using arctan is a problem, for each pixel the angles are pretty close together, so after finding the points I just do: `theta_p = np.arctan(yp/xp)

theta_q = np.arctan(yq/xq)

delta_theta = theta_q - theta_p

circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)`

The case where only 2 of the points are inside the circle is the hardest because it has the most possible outcomes. You also can't assume x or y is the same for both points, since the center might be at for example 5.2, 4.9 which doesn't line up with any grid and the two points would be different.

Comment: The best way to do it is to use a trapezoid + circle segment from what I can tell. The code is already way too long though, so I'll come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: If you use `atan` you need to control the sign of each angle. If you use `atan2` then get the minimun of `abs(atan2_q - atan2_p)` and `abs(2PI- atan2_q - atan2_q)`

Comment: The area between circumference PQ and line PQ is `A= R^2 * (delta_theta/2 - sin(delta_theta))`. Theta in radians.

Comment: if you have a look at the code I posted, I'm finding each exact possibility (the angle, number of corners that are inside, and for the case where 2 corners are inside, exactly which 2 corners are inside (P and Q would either be horizontal or vertical, depending on that)) so I don't think atan should be an issue. I've played around with it and it seems to be stable and producing correct results, but feel free to have a go at it yourself and test it. Let me know if you find anything weird.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested the code yet, but at first glance, it seems to work. I'll post it here in case anyone in the future needs something similar to this. It's near impossible to document and comment on every possible scenario so sorry about that, just use the code as is:

```
def getAngle(x,y):
    if x == 0:
        if y>0:
            return 90
        else:
            return 270
    angle = np.arctan(y/x)*180/np.pi
    if x>0:
        if y<0:
            angle+=360
    else:
        angle+=180
    return angle

def getAngleRad(x,y):
    if x == 0:
        if y>0:
            return 0.5*np.pi
        else:
            return 1.5*np.pi
    angle = np.arctan(y/x)
    if x>0:
        if y<0:
            angle+=2*np.pi
    else:
        angle+=np.pi
    return angle

def circularMask(size=3, r=1, x_offset=0, y_offset=0):
    x0 = y0 = size /2.0
    x0 += x_offset
    y0 -= y_offset
    img = np.zeros((size,size))

    for j in range(img.shape[0]):
        y = y0-j
        for i in range(img.shape[1]):
            x = i-x0
            d1 = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
            d2 = np.sqrt((x+1)**2 + y**2)
            d3 = np.sqrt(x**2 + (y-1)**2)
            d4 = np.sqrt((x+1)**2 + (y-1)**2)
            
            corners_inside = 0
            for d in [d1,d2,d3,d4]:
                if d<r:
                    corners_inside+=1

            if corners_inside==4:
                img[j,i]=1

            if corners_inside==3 or corners_inside==1:
                if x>0 and y>0:
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        xp = x+1
                        yq = y
                    else:
                        xp = x
                        yq = y-1
                    xq = np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    yp = np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)

                    traingle_area = 0.5*(xp-xq)*(yq-yp)

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)

                    if corners_inside==3:
                        img[j,i]=1-traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    else:
                        img[j,i]=traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    
                if x<0 and y>0:
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        xp = x
                        yq = y
                    else:
                        xp = x+1
                        yq = y-1
                    xq = -np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    yp = np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)

                    traingle_area = 0.5*(xq-xp)*(yq-yp)

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)

                    
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        img[j,i]=1-traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    else:
                        img[j,i]=traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    
                if x<0 and y<0:
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        xp = x
                        yq = y-1
                    else:
                        xp = x+1
                        yq = y
                    xq = -np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    yp = -np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)

                    traingle_area = 0.5*(xq-xp)*(yp-yq)

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        img[j,i]=1-traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    else:
                        img[j,i]=traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    
                if x>0 and y<0:
                    if corners_inside==3:
                        xp = x+1
                        yq = y-1
                    else:
                        xp = x
                        yq = y
                    xq = np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    yp = -np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)

                    traingle_area = 0.5*(xp-xq)*(yp-yq)

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)

                    if corners_inside==3:
                        img[j,i]=1-traingle_area+circle_segment_area
                    else:
                        img[j,i]=traingle_area+circle_segment_area

            if corners_inside==2:
                angle = getAngle(x+0.5,y-0.5)

                if angle<22.5 or angle>337.5:
                    yp = y
                    yq = y-1
                    xp = np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                    xq = np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    
                    trapezoid_area = (0.5*(xp+xq))-x
                    
                    theta_p = np.arctan(yp/xp)
                    theta_q = np.arctan(yq/xq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)

                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area
                    

                if 22.5<angle<67.5:
                    if d1<r:
                        yp = y
                        yq = y-1
                        xp = np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                        xq = np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = (0.5*(xp+xq))-x
                    else:
                        xp = x
                        xq = x+1
                        yp = np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                        yq = np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = (0.5*(yp+yq))-y+1

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)

                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 67.5<angle<112.5:
                    xp = x
                    xq = x+1
                    yp = np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                    yq = np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                    
                    trapezoid_area = (0.5*(yp+yq))-y+1

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 112.5<angle<157.5:
                    if d3< r:
                        xp = x+1
                        xq = x
                        yp = np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                        yq = np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = (0.5*(yp+yq))-y+1
                    else:
                        yp = y
                        yq = y-1
                        xp = -np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                        xq = -np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = x+1-(0.5*(xp+xq))

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 157.5<angle<202.5:
                    yp = y
                    yq = y-1
                    xp = -np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                    xq = -np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                    
                    trapezoid_area = x+1-(0.5*(xp+xq))

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 202.5<angle<247.5:
                    if d4<r:
                        yp = y
                        yq = y-1
                        xp = -np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                        xq = -np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = x+1-(0.5*(xp+xq))
                    else:
                        xp = x
                        xq = x+1
                        yp = -np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                        yq = -np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = y-(0.5*(yp+yq))

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 247.5<angle<292.5:
                    xp = x
                    xq = x+1
                    yp = -np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                    yq = -np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                    
                    trapezoid_area = y-(0.5*(yp+yq))

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

                if 292<angle<337.5:
                    if d3<r:
                        yp = y
                        yq = y-1
                        xp = np.sqrt(r**2-yp**2)
                        xq = np.sqrt(r**2-yq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = (0.5*(xp+xq))-x
                    else:
                        xq = x
                        xp = x+1
                        yp = -np.sqrt(r**2-xp**2)
                        yq = -np.sqrt(r**2-xq**2)
                        trapezoid_area = y-(0.5*(yp+yq))

                    theta_p = getAngleRad(xp,yp)
                    theta_q = getAngleRad(xq,yq)
                    delta_theta = np.abs(theta_p - theta_q)

                    circle_segment_area = 0.5*(delta_theta-np.sin(delta_theta))*(r**2)
                    
                    img[j,i] = trapezoid_area+circle_segment_area

    return img
```

the output matches the expected result for the values posted in the question:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: I've found a few bugs and solved them (code is updated), but beware, there might be more that I haven't discovered yet. Use the code at your own risk.